# How long is a mean Jovian tropical year in Jovian solar days?

Tags: orbit, jupiter, sidereal-period

Many sources say that Jupiter's year lasts 10,475.8 Jovian days. When I calculated to see if that's correct With the data NASA had published, I found out it's the measurement of a Jovian sidereal year. How many Jovian solar days are there in one mean Jovian tropical year EXACTLY?

Answer (score 3):

A quick search on Google brings us to https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/jupiterfact.html where it is mentioned that Jupiter’s tropical year lasts 4,330.595 Earth days and that the length of its day is 9.9259 Earth hours.

Doing a little bit of math gives us the answer to your question…

4,330.595 × 24 = 103,934.28 hours
103,934.28 ÷ 9.9259 = 10,471.01825… Jovian days